# Formatting style of page printing

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I'm trying to create a page for printing labels, but when the divs go to the next page, there is a gap between the top of the page and its contents. But I don't want any gaps. I have tried different breakpage and other methods, but nothing is working. Can someone help?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Label Printer</title>
    <style>
        body {
            display: block;
            max-width: 215.9mm;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        div {
            width: 44.2%;
            height: 37.125mm;
            float: left;
            border: 2px solid rgb(119, 205, 255);
            border-radius: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            margin-right: 2px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        p {
            cursor: pointer;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <style media="print">
        @page {
            height: 305mm;
            width: 215.9mm;
            margin-top: 5mm;
            margin-left: 0.6cm;
            margin-right: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        div {
            border: 0px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            text-align: left;
        }

        p {
            padding-left: 0;
            border: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
        }

        function drop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="dor div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag1">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby
            ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag2">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby
            ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag3">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby
            ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag4">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby
            ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag5">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby
            ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div6" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag6">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby
            ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div7" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag7">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby
            ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div8" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag8">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby
            ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div9" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag9">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby
            ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div10" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag10">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary
            road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div12" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag11">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary
            road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div13" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag12">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary
            road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div14" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag13">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary
            road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div15" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag14">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary
            road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div16" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag15">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary
            road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div17" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag16">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary
            road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div18" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag17">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary
            road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div19" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag18">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary
            road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div20" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag19">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary
            road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div21" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag20">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary
            road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div22" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="dor drag21">michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary
            road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dor div23" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="dor div24" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="dor div25" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="dor div26" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="dor div27" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="dor div28" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="dor div29" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="dor div30" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="dor div31" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="dor div32" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="dor div33" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="dor div34" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <script>
        function hider(id) {
            var b = document.getElementById(id);
            b.style.display = 'none';
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the page whose format I want for all other pages.

[image]

This is with fault

[image]

**Note**:This can sometimes contain 90 to 100 div(Labels).

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried different breakpage and other methods but not working.

Well that's because you are using [`float: left` and print css doesnt like it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472632/how-can-i-fix-this-print-layout-with-float-in-print-stylesheet)

One of the options is to use `inline-block`

```css
div {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block; 
}
```

After that there comes another issue

[image]

Perhaps `margin/height` value manipulation at specific child `:nth-child(n)` might fill the gap

**This one did the trick for my browser but I don't guarantee that result will be the same across all browsers**

```css
div:nth-child(15), div:nth-child(16) {
   margin-top: -18.5px;
}
```

Good luck!